# How to add current URL parameter to all links on page

Tags: javascript

I am not confident with Javascript - hoping there is a quick way to take a parameter from current URL and use javascript to add it to all links on the page.

eg  current URL `www.website.com/salespage?affiliate_id=1234`
and then have `affiliate_id=1234` added to the end of all links on the page, ie
`www.website.com/orderpage?affiliate_id=1234`  and `www.website.com/orderpage2?affiliate_id=1234`

I've been searching for javascript code but found some that capture the existing parameter, and some that insert a parameter to a URL but not how to make it all work together?

```
<script>
  function getUrlParam(affiliate_id, defaultvalue){
    var urlparameter = defaultvalue;
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(parameter) > -1){
        urlparameter = getUrlVars()[parameter];
        }
    return urlparameter;
}

  var addthis_share = {
     url_transforms : {
         add: {
             affiliate_id: urlparameter,
         }
     } 
} 
</script>
```

I want the URL links to be updated to be such as www.website.com/orderpage?affiliate_id=1234
currently not working at all

Comment: All solutions provided do not work in case the URL contains query parameters via "?" or anchors "#" already. I found a solution on that page which describes the problem pretty well: https://blog.miguelbernard.com/how-to-dynamically-add-a-query-string-to-all-links-in-a-page

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it on `document ready` of jquery, loop `each` a tag and update `href` attribute to add your parameter

```
$(function() {
   $("a").attr('href', function(index, item) {
     return item + (item.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&affiliate_id=1234" : "?affiliate_id=1234");
   });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
   $("a").attr('href', function(index, item) {
     return item + (item.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&affiliate_id=1234" : "?affiliate_id=1234");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Test1</h2>
<a href="/test">Test1</a>
<h2>Test2</h2>
<a href="/test?param=1">Test2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use javascript, you can implement `onload` event and get all a tag by `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` and use `for` loop to update your param.

Update:

If you want to get affiliate ID from current url, you can use

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
 let affiliate_id = getParameterByName('affiliate_id');
 for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href += anchors[i].href.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&affiliate_id=" + affiliate_id  : "?affiliate_id=" + affiliate_id;
 }
}
```

```html
<h2>Test1</h2>
<a href="/test">Test1</a>
<h2>Test2</h2>
<a href="/test?param=1">Test2</a>
```

Comment: Hi Hien, thanks for replying to my query. The affiliate ID could be different as there are many affiliates with their own IDs so it needs to be loading it dynamically depending on the current URL, so it needs to retrieve the value from current URL to append to URLs on the page. If it could avoid adding it to anchor links that would be great!

Comment: Thank you this is working for the links now! Is there a way to NOT add the affiliate link if there is a # in the link (ie for anchor links on the page)? It's stopping the anchor link from working as it's inserting the affiliate info when it doesn't need to). Ie if there is a '#' in the URL it doesn't append the affiliate_id?
  
www.website.com?affiliate_id=1368906#scroll-Get%20Tickets%20Now&affiliate_id=1368906